# I am not getting desired ouput

Tags: java

Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.
My code looks okay. 
But I am not getting desired output.

```
//My code       
public class NewClass{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        lar();
    }
    public static void lar(){
        long a = 999L;
        long b = 999L;
        int ct = 0;
        while(a > 99){
            while(b > 99){
                long c = a * b;
                if(isPalindrome(c)){
                    System.out.println(a + "  " + b);
                    System.out.println(c);
                    ct++;
                    break;
               }
               b = b - 1;
            }
            a = a - 1;
            if(ct > 0){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    public static boolean isPalindrome(long number){
        long n = 0L;
        long plnum = 0L;
        long num = number;
        while(number != 0){
            n = number % 10;
            plnum = plnum * 10;
            plnum = plnum + n;
            number = number / 10;
        }
        if(num == plnum){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the desired output? What is your current output?

Comment: And hint: "code looking okay" doesn't matter. What matters is what it does. And honestly, it doesn't look okay. For example naming of variables is pretty "not helpful". "num = number" tells the reader nothing. Not okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In outer loop reset the value of b.

```
         while(a > 99){
            while(b > 99){
               if(isPalindrome()){
               .....
               }
               b = b - 1;
            }
            a = a - 1;
            b=999L;// <---------------- this
          }
```